# Why is my CPU not maxed out?

Tags: cpu, javascript, cpu-usage

I have a simple Node script in VS Code that is:

- instantiating a 300x300x300 array of booleans, initializing every element to `false`
- iterating through the array to flip true/false depending on a condition
- repeating the above about 1000 times

Memory used by Code is about 1GB. Everything is in variables in memory. There is no IO, no screen output. Code is using only 14% of CPU on my 11th generation I7. Javascript runs only on a single thread. Why isn't it maxed out on the core that it is running in?

[image]

Why isn't CPU utilization higher when everything is running in memory? Where is the bottleneck or what is throttling it?

The slowest part of my code seems to be creating the array. I am using this code:

```
const cubeSize = 300;
const grid = [];
for (let x = 0; x < cubeSize; x++) {
  const ydimension = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < cubeSize; y++) {
    const zdimension = Array(cubeSize).fill(false);
    ydimension.push(zdimension);
  };
  grid.push(ydimension);
};
```

Comment: You aren't using the whole CPU, you are using one (maybe two) cores. Code cannot natively run on more than one core at a time without effort on your part.

Comment: While the duplicate is about python, the answer is the same. Unless you have written your program to use more cores it will be inherently limited to 1 for your program and maybe 1 for whatever the interpreter needs to do.

Comment: Node/Javascript is single thread, no issue with that. My question is why isn't one core maxed out?

Comment: Why do you expect it to use one core at 100% utilization?

Comment: What's holding it back? Unlikely RAM cache access speed is slower than core speed as it would make the hardware configuration meaningless. Could it be Windows rotating the JS thread from core to core?

Comment: One core isn't maxed out because the program is being rapidly stopped and started on different cores by the operating system scheduler. Essentially the program is being smeared across all the cores over time but at any given moment it can only run on one core.

Comment: To give more context, it is a feature of every modern multi-tasking operating system. Computers are more complex than ever and operating systems are a collection of programs all vying for time on the processor, they may not all need much time overall but there are hundreds of processes that all need to run over time and in order to be "fair" the operating system does not assume that any one program should monopolise a CPU exclusively. As a result a program will get de-scheduled, other programs will run, and by the time the OS gets back to your program it may have to run on another core.

Comment: If you do want your program to run exclusively on one core you can set up the [process affinity](https://superuser.com/search?q=task+affinity) but you may be restricting the programs ability to use multi-threading when supported. You are better off just leaving it to the operating system to do the job it was designed for.